# Drum.js Date Box only selected option visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm using drum.js, a jquery plugin to create a date box that mimics the iphone date roller. [github repo](https://github.com/3epnm/drumjs)

[Demo](https://mb.aquarius.uberspace.de/drumjs/examples/datetime_range.html)

First I copied the code and made adjustments for my page and it didn't work, so I just copied and pasted to see if the sample code would work on my page and it doesn't.

[image: Screenshot with no highlighted select]
[image: Screenshot with one select highlighted]

I've tried setting the background of the whole area and all inner divs to white, and the color for all divs to black. Nothing seems to help.

I'm using bootstrap3 for my site.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the other options to show?

Thank you so much!

CSS:

```
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/drum/drum.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type='text/css'>
div.date_wrapper {
width: 200px;
position:relative;
}
div.date_wrapper .date_header {
height: 25px;
font-weight: 400;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div.date_wrapper .date_header span.title {
float: left;
text-align: left;
}
div.date_wrapper .date_header span.selection {
float: right;
text-align: right;
color: #000;
}
div.date_wrapper form {
position: relative;
}
div.date_wrapper .lines {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-top: solid 1px #CCC;
border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
position: absolute;
top: 58px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 24px;
}
div.date_wrapper .lines div {
margin-left: 220px;
line-height: 21px;
}
div.drum-wrapper {
float: left;
}
div.drum figure {
color:#000;
text-align: left;
}
#drum_hours figure,  #drum_date figure {
text-align: right;
}
#drum_date, #drum_to_date {
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
#drum_date,  #drum_hours,  #drum_minutes {
width: 30px;
}
#drum_hours {
margin-left: 10px;
}
#drum_minutes {
margin-left: 4px;
}
#drum_month {
width: 90px;
}
#drum_fullYear {
width: 45px;
}
#drum_hours .dial div {
margin: 0 7px;
}
#drum_minutes .dial div {
margin: 0 2px;
}
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div class='date_wrapper outside'>
<div class="lines"></div> <div class='inside'><select class="date" id="date" name="date" data-for='primary_date_of_birth'> <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select></div>
    <div class='inside'><select class="date" id="month" name="month" data-for='primary_date_of_birth'><option value='0'>ינואר</option><option value='1'>פברואר</option><option value='2'>מרץ</option><option value='3'>אפריל</option><option value='4'>מאי</option><option value='5'>יוני</option><option value='6'>יולי</option><option value='7'>אוגוסט</option><option value='8'>ספטמבר</option><option value='9'>אוקטובר</option><option value='10'>נובמבר</option><option value='11'>דצמבר</option></select></div><div class='inside'>
    <select class="date" id="fullYear" name="fullYear" data-for='primary_date_of_birth'><option value='1936'>1936</option><option value='1937'>1937</option><option value='1938'>1938</option><option value='1939'>1939</option><option value='1940'>1940</option><option value='1941'>1941</option><option value='1942'>1942</option><option value='1943'>1943</option><option value='1944'>1944</option><option value='1945'>1945</option><option value='1946'>1946</option><option value='1947'>1947</option><option value='1948'>1948</option><option value='1949'>1949</option><option value='1950'>1950</option><option value='1951'>1951</option><option value='1952'>1952</option><option value='1953'>1953</option><option value='1954'>1954</option><option value='1955'>1955</option><option value='1956'>1956</option><option value='1957'>1957</option><option value='1958'>1958</option><option value='1959'>1959</option><option value='1960'>1960</option><option value='1961'>1961</option><option value='1962'>1962</option><option value='1963'>1963</option><option value='1964'>1964</option><option value='1965'>1965</option><option value='1966'>1966</option><option value='1967'>1967</option><option value='1968'>1968</option><option value='1969'>1969</option><option value='1970'>1970</option><option value='1971'>1971</option><option value='1972'>1972</option><option value='1973'>1973</option><option value='1974'>1974</option><option value='1975'>1975</option><option value='1976'>1976</option><option value='1977'>1977</option><option value='1978'>1978</option><option value='1979'>1979</option><option value='1980'>1980</option><option value='1981'>1981</option><option value='1982'>1982</option><option value='1983'>1983</option><option value='1984'>1984</option><option value='1985'>1985</option><option value='1986'>1986</option><option value='1987'>1987</option><option value='1988'>1988</option><option value='1989'>1989</option><option value='1990'>1990</option><option value='1991'>1991</option><option value='1992'>1992</option><option value='1993'>1993</option><option value='1994'>1994</option><option value='1995'>1995</option><option value='1996'>1996</option><option value='1997'>1997</option></select></div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
        Hammer.plugins.fakeMultitouch();
function getIndexForValue(elem, value) {
for (var i=0; i<elem.options.length; i++)
if (elem.options[i].value == value)
return i;
}

function pad(number) {
if ( number < 10 ) {
return '0' + number;
}
return number;
}

function updateIDate(datetime) {
$("#date").drum('setIndex', datetime.getDate()-1); 
$("#month").drum('setIndex', datetime.getMonth()); 
$("#fullYear").drum('setIndex', getIndexForValue($("#fullYear")[0], datetime.getFullYear())); 
}

$("select.date").drum({
onChange : function (elem) {
var arr = {'date' : 'setDate', 'month' : 'setMonth', 'fullYear' : 'setFullYear'};
var date = new Date();
var hidden_input = '';
for (var s in arr) {
console.log(s);
var select = $($(" select[name='" + s + "']")[0]);
var i = select.val()
eval ("date." + arr[s] + "(" + i + ")");
hidden_input = select.data('for');
}
date.setSeconds(0);
updateIDate(date);

var format = date.getFullYear() + '-' + pad( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + pad( date.getDate() ) ;
$('#' + hidden_input).val(format);
$('.date_header .selection').html(format);
console.log('the date:', format);

}
});
updateIDate(new Date());


/* end Date box plugin */
        }
```

Comment: Have you included drum.css file??

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to display.

Comment: @ArunDNambissan: I added the code, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: i am having this problem to. any solution?